# Values not updating when using functions to assign templates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this HTML and am trying to use it to generate a table with the option to add more rows:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: item }">
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: cost() }"></td>
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: amount() }">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using two different templates:

```
<script id="inpTmp" type="text/html">
    <input data-bind="value: $data" />
</script>
<script id="dispTmp" type="text/html">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</script>
```

and am choosing  which one to call based on the results of the `dynTemplate` function. The knockout that I have powering this is very simple:

```
function ItemAdd(name, icost, iamount) {
    var self = this;
    self.item = name;
    self.cost = ko.observable(icost);
    self.amount = ko.observable(iamount);
}
function TestModel() {
    var self= this;
    self.items= ko.observableArray([
        new ItemAdd("a", 5, 10),
        new ItemAdd("b", 6, 4)
    ]);
    self.addItem= function() {
        self.items.push(new ItemAdd("", 0, 0));
    };
    self.dynTemplate= function(init, s) {
        if(init=== 0 || init=== '') {
            return 'inpTmp';
        }
        return 'dispTmp';
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new TestModel());
```

The problem that I am running into is that when I enter values into newly created rows, the values in `items` do not change. They initialize properly, but when I run a function to log the values in `items` they stay as their defaults. If I use knockout `if` statements, then everything updates properly. However, using 6 sets of `if` statements didn't seem very effective so I wanted to see if I could pull it out into a function and then send back the proper template. I'm trying to have inputs there when the value is `""` or 0, and then change them to `<p>` when something is entered.

I've tried changing how the data is passed into the template, and I've tried to assign context using `with`, but to no avail. Calling `dynTemplate` does not work unless prefixed by `$root` or `$parent`. If that is changing the context, is there a way to reset it?

Is this a problem of context, and if so, is there a way to assign context with the `dynTemplate` function? Or are the newly created elements from the template not properly binding? I've searched quite a bit, and have found templates within foreach loops, but have not seen functions being used to apply them. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Thank you for the help

Comment: The dynTemplate function is requiring arguments, which as far as I can tell are not being passed in when you do your template binding in the HTML.  Have you tried having the 'init' be an observable in your TestModel and having the dynTemplate be a ko.computed()?

Comment: You are binding to values `cost()`, `amount()` when you should bind to observables `cost`, `amount`.

Comment: @xDaevax when I log `init` within `dynTemplate` it gives the value of the data that's passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current sample doesn't work because ko dependency tacker doesn't see that your model field is changed. It happens because 'init' is unwrapped value (not an observable).
This fiddle shows how to make it work with single 'item' field.
http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/VXXqr/

In this changed version of dynTemplate we get the value of observable, and thus dependency tracker can see that value changed. Of course, we need to change the template.

```
self.dynTemplate= function(item, s) {
    var val = item.item();
    if(val=== 0 || val=== '') {
        return 'inpTmp';
    }
    return 'dispTmp';
};

<script id="inpTmp" type="text/html">
    <input data-bind="value: $data.item" />
</script>
<script id="dispTmp" type="text/html">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.item"></p>
</script>
```

For your case, where you need universal template for all fields you can do the following: pass as data the name of the field. The template will pick up data from $parent. dynTemplate func is changed accordingly.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: 'item' }">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: 'cost' }">    
        </td>
        <td data-bind="template: {name: $parent.dynTemplate, data: 'amount' }">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<script id="inpTmp" type="text/html">
    <input data-bind="value: $parent[$data]" />
</script>
<script id="dispTmp" type="text/html">
    <p data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></p>
</script>

self.dynTemplate= function(field, context) {
    var value = context.$parent[field]();
    if(value=== 0 || value=== '') {
        return 'inpTmp';
    }
    return 'dispTmp';
};
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/VXXqr/5/